# Extract the first 2 fields from a CSV file (may contain commas or quotes)

Tags: bash, csv, parsing, awk, command-line

I have a CSV file with 3 or more fields, and I want to extract the first 2 fields as they are, and save them to a new file. Notice that the fields may be quoted or not, and may contain commas or quotes (doubled). I want to extract the first 2 fields exactly as they are (either quoted or not), and ignore the third field and other fields if they are. This should be done from the command line. Currently I have this command:

```
cat 1.csv | awk -F, '{print $1","$2}' > 2.csv
```

But this doesn't work if there is a comma in the fields.

A field may be empty (not containing anything, not even quotes).

(I also checked [Ignoring comma in field of CSV file with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477652/ignoring-comma-in-field-of-csv-file-with-awk) but the answers there don't work for me)

**Update**: This question is different because it requires the CSV format to be the same as the original format - either quoted or unquoted fields. I have a solution which I want to submit.

Comment: You should provide sample input CSV and expected output.

Comment: A CSV field can contain the CSV separator, quotes and newlines. To handle this situation, you can either reinvent the wheel and write another CSV parser (in addition to the many which already exist), or you use an existing one. I'm using the one which comes with Ruby, and in the past also used the one in Perl. Probably there is one for your favorite programming language as well.

Comment: Can you use a non-standard CSV-aware command-line tool?

Comment: @ZachYoung Yes.

Comment: The second duplicate has many answers which don't work with any CSV file, but also many which do.

Answer (score 1):

Given this input file containing quoted fields that contain embedded quotes, commas, and newlines:

```
$ cat file.csv
"foo,""bar""",2,3
1,"foo,bar",3
1,"foo,
bar",3
```

then using GNU awk 5.3 or later for CSV processing:

```
$ awk --csv -v OFS=',' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { gsub(/"/,"\"\"",$i); if ($i ~ /[,\n"]/) $i="\"" $i "\"" } print $1, $2}' file.csv
"foo,""bar""",2
1,"foo,bar"
1,"foo,
bar"
```

The quotes required in CSV format to protect field contents are stripped when the input is read so we had to add them back before printing otherwise we'd get this output:

```
$ awk --csv -v OFS=',' '{print $1, $2}' file.csv
foo,"bar",2
1,foo,bar
1,foo,
bar
```

which is not valid CSV.

See also [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk).

Answer (score 0):

GoCSV has the [select subcommand](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/#select) which allows use to select which columns to keep (or exclude) from the specified (or piped-in) CSV.  GoCSV is [prebuilt](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases/tag/v1.0.2) for a number of modern platforms.

Starting with this input CSV:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
"foo, bar",baz,baker
"Foo, Bar",Baz,baker
```

You can call gocsv directly on the file:

```
gocsv select -c 1,2 input.csv
```

or pipe the CSV in:

```
cat input.csv | gocsv select -c 1,2
```

to get:

```
Col1,Col2
"foo, bar",baz
"Foo, Bar",Baz
```

GoCSV always interprets the first row as a header (and uses the header so you can call-out columns by name, if you like). If your original doesn't have a header, you can start with the cap subcommand to add a temporary header, pipe that into select, then pipe that into the behead subcommand to remove the temp header.

Add the cap:

```
echo \"foo, bar\",baz,baker\\n\"Foo, Bar\",Baz,Baker | gocsv cap -names Col1,Col2,Col3

Col1,Col2,Col3
"foo, bar",baz,baker
"Foo, Bar",Baz,Baker
```

```
... | gocsv select -c 1,2 | gocsv behead

"foo, bar",baz
"Foo, Bar",Baz
```

The cap subcommand has the -default-name option, but it doesn't work without providing at least on explicit column name with -names.